# Umbraco, get node by name and datatype

Tags: c#, select, umbraco, nodes

I have a datatype called "Demo" I also have a page/node with the name "Test"..
How would I select this page/node if im not in any type of context?

I have tried using new Node(-1) and select my way down but I really cant figure this one out..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use one of the following [uQuery](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/) extensions:

- [GetNodesByName(string)](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/Content/Nodes#GetNodesByName%28string%29)
- [GetNodesByType(string or int)](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/Content/Nodes#GetNodesByType%28stringorint%29)

Here's a couple examples:

**GetNodesByName(string):**

```
umbraco.NodeFactory.Node node = uQuery.GetNodesByName("Page Name")
    .Where(n => n.NodeTypeAlias == "NodeTypeAlias").FirstOrDefault();

if (node != null)
{
    //...
}
```

**GetNodesByType(string or int):**

```
umbraco.NodeFactory.Node node = uQuery.GetNodesByType("NodeTypeAlias")
    .Where(n => n.Name == "Page Name").FirstOrDefault();

if (node != null)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Since Document is node that are published, and there's no method GetDocumentByName() how do you get only the node that are published or check if a node is published?

Comment: Ok it seems to return only the ones that are published, what can I do if I want the unpublished node by name?

Comment: `Node` allows access to published nodes or nodes that are in the XML cache, whereas `Document` allows access to all nodes including unpublished ones or all nodes in the database. Since querying the database is expensive, I wouldn't advise getting the node by name, but if you really need to you could get all of the descendants of root and then the first that matches the specific name.

Answer (score 6):

With Umbraco 6+ I think this would be preferable...

```
public static IPublishedContent GetNodeByAlias(string alias)
{
    var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
    var contentNode = umbracoHelper.TypedContentSingleAtXPath(String.Format("//{0}", alias));

    return contentNode;
}
```

This just takes a document type alias and finds your node as IPublishedContent using the current Umbraco context. UmbracoHelper gives you quite a few options off this also.